# What is the SIGKILL permissions policy?

Tags: linux, process, posix, signals, sigkill

What is the SIGKILL permissions policy?

I assume I can't kill something of the kernel, or of some other user, while running on non-root, but I haven't found any document about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://linux.die.net/man/2/kill :

> For a process to have permission to
>   send a signal it must either be
>   privileged (under Linux: have the
>   CAP_KILL capability), or the real or
>   effective user ID of the sending
>   process must equal the real or saved
>   set-user-ID of the target process. In
>   the case of SIGCONT it suffices when
>   the sending and receiving processes
>   belong to the same session.